# characters in c and c++

Tags: c++, c

What I ask about is(is my understanding totally true ?)

char x='b'; (x has one value can be represented with two ways one of them is **int** and the other is **char** in the two languages **( C and C++)**)

**in C**

if I let the compiler choose it will choose (Will give priority to) the **int** value because the standard of the C makes character literal as int (give priority to int not char) like in this code

```
int main(){
    printf("%d", sizeof('b'));
    return 0;}
```

**output is: 4 (int size) that is meaning the compiler treat b as 98 first and get the size it as int**

but I can use the **char** value if I choose like in this code

```
int main(){
    char x = 'b';
    printf("%c", x);
    return 0;}
```

**output is: b (char)**

**in C ++**

if I let the compiler choose it will choose (Will give priority to) the **char** value because the standard of the C++ makes character literal as char (give priority to char not int) like in this code

```
int main(){
    printf("%d", sizeof('b'));
    return 0;}
```

**output is:1 (char size) that is meaning the compiler treat b as char**

but I can use the **int** value if I choose like in this code

```
int main(){
        char x = 'b';
        printf("%d", x);
        return 0;}
```

**output is 98 (98 is the int which represents b in the ASCII Code )**

Comment: Apart from the obviousness that `printf("%d", sizeof('b');` isn't valid C *or* C++ code (there is no closing paren for the `printf` call), you're also sending a `size_t`  argument to `printf` with a `int` format specifier, which is wrong. `%zu` is the proper specifier.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: there's no relationship whatsoever between the size of a type and the properties of it. `char` is just another integral type like `int`

Comment: Your understanding is correct. In C (and where relevant in C++) all character values are read as `unsigned char` cast to `int`. See [man 3 fgetc](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fgetc.3.html) under "RETURN VALUE". This `unsigned char` is your ASCII code. By casing to `int` the function return can be validly compared against `int` values such as `EOF`. So the `unsigned char` value of `'b'` is `98` which you can see in the ASCII table. Functions like `fgetc()` cast to `int` to facilitate return checking. In `printf("%d", x);`, `x` is implicitly converted to `int`, better to use `%hhu`.

Comment: A character literal is an int in C and a char in C++.

Answer (score 2):

- *Character constants*, this: `'A'`, are of type `int` in C and of type `char` in C++. The compiler picks the type specified by the respective language standard.
- Declared character variables of type `char` are always `char` and 1 byte large (typically 8 bits on non-exotic systems).
- `printf("%c", some_char);` is a *variadic function* (accepts any number of parameters) and those have special implicit type promotion rules. Something called *default argument promotion* will integer-promote the passed character variable to `int`. Read about integer promotion here: [Implicit type promotion rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46073295/implicit-type-promotion-rules).

  `printf` expects that promotion to happen, so `%c` will mean that parameter is converted back to `char` according to the internals of `printf`. This holds true in C++ as well, though stdio.h should be avoided.
- `printf("%d", x);` In case `x` is a `char` this would pedantically be undefined behavior. But in practice the above mentioned integer promotion is likely to occur and so it prints an integer. Also note that there's nothing magic with `char` as such, they are just 1 byte large integers. So it already has the value 98 before conversion.

Comment: I changed some things can you take a look and answer me (is my understanding totally true now?) @Lundin

Comment: You said " Character constants, this: 'A', are of type int in C and of type char in C++. The compiler picks the type specified by the respective language standard. "
What is the meaning of " this "  in your answer ?  @Lundin

Comment: @FadyHany The meaning of a colon `:` in any language using Latin letters such as English is roughly "here follows".

Comment: So the meaning of " this " in the quote is 'A' , right ? @Lundin

Answer (score 2):

Some of the things you've said are true, some are mistaken.  Let's go through them in turn.

> `char x='b';` (`x` has two values one of them is `int` and the other is `char` in the two languages ( C and C++))

Well, no, not really.  When you say `char x` you get a variable generally capable of holding one character, and this is perfectly, equally true in both C and C++.  The only difference, as we'll see, is the *type* (*not* the value) of  the character constant `'b'`.

> in C if I let the compiler choose

I'm not sure what you mean by "choose", because there's not really any choice in the matter.

> it will choose (Will give priority to) the `int` value like in this code
> `printf("%d", sizeof('b'));`
> output is: 4 (int size) that is meaning the compiler change b to 98 first and get the size it as `int`

Not exactly.  You got 4 because, yes, the *type* of a character constant like `'b'` is `int`.  In ASCII, the character constant `'b'` has the value 98 no matter what.  The compiler didn't change a character to an int here, and the value didn't change from `'b'` to 98 here.  It was an int all along (because that's the type of character constants in C), and it had the value 98 all along (because that's the value of the letter `b` in ASCII).

> but I can use the char value if I choose like in this code
> `printf("%c", x);

Right.  But there's nothing magical about that.  Consider:

```
char c1 = 'b';
int i1 = 'b';
char c2 = 98;
int i2 = 98;
printf("%c %c %c %c\n", c1, i1, c2, i2);
printf("%d %d %d %d\n", c1, i1, c2, i2);
```

This prints

```
b b b b
98 98 98 98
```

You can print an `int`, or a `char`, using `%c`, and you'll get the character with that value.
You can print an `int`, or a `char`, using `%d`, and you'll get a numeric value.
(More on this later.)

> in C ++ if I let the compiler choose it will choose (Will give priority to) the char value like in this code
> `printf("%d", sizeof('b'));`
> output is:1 (char size) that is meaning the compiler did not change `b` to `int`

What you're seeing is one of the big differences between C and C++: character constants like `'b'` are type `int` in C, but type `char` in C++.
(Why is it this way?  I'll speculate on that later.)

> but I can use the int value if I choose like in this code
> `char x = 'b';`
> `printf("%d", x);`
> output is 98 (98 is the int which represents `b` in the ASCII Code )

Right.  And this would work exactly the same in C and C++.  (Also my earlier printfs of `c1`, `i1`, `c2`, and `i2` would work exactly the same in C and C++.)

So why are the types of character constants different?  I'm not sure, but I believe it's like this:

C likes to promote everything to `int`.  (Incidentally, that's why we were able to pass characters straight to `printf` and print them using `%d`: the characters all get promoted to `int` before being passed to `printf`, so it works just fine.)  So there would be no point having character constants of type `char`, because any time you used one, for anything, it would get promoted to `int`.  So character constants might as well start out being `int`.

In C++, on the other hand, the type of things matters more.  And you might have two overloaded functions, `f(int)` and `f(char)`, and if you called `f('b')`, clearly you want the version of `f()` called that accepts a `char`.  So in C++ there was a reason, a good reason, to have character constants be type `char`, just like it looks like they are.

---

Addendum:

The fundamental issue that you're asking about here, that we've been kind of dancing around in this answer and these comments, is that in C (as in most languages) there are several forms of constant, that let you write constants in forms that are convenient and meaningful to you.  For any different form of constant you can write, there are several things of interest, but most importantly *what is the actual value?* and *what is the type?*.

It may be easier to show this by example.  Here is a rather large number of ways of representing the constant value 98 in a C or C++ program:

| Form of constant | base | type | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `98` | 10 | int | 98 |
| `0142` | 8 | unsigned | 98 |
| `0x62` | 16 | unsigned | 98 |
| `98.` | 10 | double | 98 |
| `9.8e1` | 10 | double | 98 |
| `98.f` | 10 | float | 98 |
| `9.8e1f` | 10 | float | 98 |
| `98L` | 10 | long | 98 |
| `98U` | 10 | unsigned | 98 |
| `'b'` | ASCII | int/char | 98 |

This table is not even complete; there are more ways than these to write constants in C and C++.

But with one exception, every row in this table is equally true of both C and C++, *except* the last row.  In C, the type of a character constant is `int`.  In C++, the type of a character constant is `char`.

The type of a constant determines what happens when a constant appears in a larger expression.  In that respect the type of a constant functions analogously to the type of a variable.  If I write

```
int a = 1, b = 3;
double c = a / b;
```

it doesn't work right, because the rule in C is that when you divide an int by an int, you get truncating integer division.  But the point is that *the type of an operand directly determines the meaning of an expression*.  So the type of a constant becomes very interesting, too, as seen by the different behavior of these two lines:

```
double c2 = 1 / 3;
double c3 = 1. / 3;
```

Similarly, it can make a difference whether a constant has type `int` or type `char`.  An expression that depends on whether a character constant has type `int` or type `char` will behave slightly differently in C versus C++.  (In practice, pretty much the only difference that can be easily seen concerns `sizeof`.)

For completeness, it may be useful to look at the several other forms of character constant, in the same framework:

| Form of constant | base | type | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `'b'` | ASCII | int/char | 98 |
| `'\142'` | 8 | int/char | 98 |
| `'\x62'` | 16 | int/char | 98 |

Comment: I changed some things can you take a look and answer me
 
(is my understanding totally true now?)
@Steve Summit

Comment: @FadyHany Your edits don't change much for me.  You're still saying things like "if I let the compiler choose it will choose (Will give priority to) the int value".  That's not *wrong*, per se, but it doesn't really mean anything, either.  It doesn't really match the model the compiler is using; it doesn't really tell you anything useful about the use of character constants in the programs you're writing.  I've added a section to my answer giving what I think *is* a useful model and explanation of the way constants work in C and C++.

Comment: If we ignore the section of "if I let the compiler choose " my understanding will be totally true (nothing wrong)? @Steve Summit

Comment: @FadyHany I think the point you're still missing is that there's not such a big difference between characters and integers in C and C++.  I don't believe it's useful to think of *converting* a character like `b` to an integer.  In both C and C++,  a character like `b` *is* an integer.  Inside the computer it's represented by the binary number `01100010`, which is the exact same way the number 98 is represented.  If you've got the binary number `01100010` stored in a register, you literally can't tell if it's the number 98 or the character `b`.

Comment: i understood that char is an int in the memory it just can be represented as char by %c 
and octal and hexadecimal are also integers in the memory 
is this what you meaning ?@Steve Summit

Comment: @FadyHany Yes, that's what I meant.  But I am not going to be able to tell you whether your understanding is now correct or not, because I cannot know that.

Comment: okay but do you have any thing you that you do not agree with me in my post except this point 
the point you do not agree is (i said the compiler choose and you said char is int in the memory compiler do not choose)
@Steve summit

Comment: @FadyHany All I can teach you I have written in my answer.

Comment: my last question 
octal(BASE 8) is an int and hexadecimal(BASE 16) is an int in C and C++right?
@Steve Summit

Comment: @FadyHany Please ask a fresh question.  This comment thread has gotten too long.